# Error: unknown type name 'record'

Tags: c, struct, void

This is my code in codeblocks C language
*sorry i'm new in here*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record
{
char name[50];
char id[30];
char course[7];
char project[100];
char field[3];
char supervisor[30];

};

struct record addname();
void list_func(record);

int main()
{
struct record student1,student2;

student1=addname();
student2=addname();

printf("\n\n\tUNDERGRADUATE PROJECT RECORD SYSTEM");
list_func(student1);
list_func(student2);

   getch();
}
struct record addname()
{
    struct record system;
    printf("\nEnter student's Name: ");
    gets(system.name);
    printf("Enter matrix's ID: ");
    gets(system.id);
    printf("Enter course's Name: ");
    gets(system.course);
    printf("Enter Project Title: ");
    gets(system.project);
    printf("Enter Field: ");
    gets(system.field);
    printf("Enter Supervisor's name: ");
    gets(system.supervisor);
    return (system);
}

void list_func(record list)
{
    printf("\n\nStudent's Name: %s",list.name);
    printf("\nMatrix ID: %s",list.id);
    printf("\nCourse: %s",list.course);
    printf("\nProject's Title: %s",list.project);
    printf("\nField: %s",list.field);
    printf("\nSupervisor: %s",list.supervisor);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n------------------------------------------------");

   return;
}
```

Okay, this is my errors:

at line 17,

```
void list_func(record);
```

at line 50,

```
void list_func(record list)
```

it says

```
line 17    warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
line 50    error: Unknown type name 'record'
           in function 'main'
line 31    warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn=type]
```

seriously i don't get it why is that. I use my friend's coding as reference and change it a lil bit and then failed to debug.
And i even copied and paste my friend's code at my codeblocks project but it still can't run
But it can run perfectly at her codeblocks project.
Can anyone help me?
I'm not so good in coding

Comment: In C++, a type defined as `struct record { ... }` can be referred to either as `struct record` or as `record`. In C, the type name is `struct record`. Also, *never* use `gets`; it is inherently unsafe, and was removed from the language in the most recent standard. `fgets` is safer (it lets you specify the size of the destination buffer and avoid overflow), though it's a little more complicated to use (it leaves the `'\n'` in the destination buffer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void list_func(record); ==> void list_func(struct record);
```

To avoid first two errors

just change parameter type in the declaration of function and defination.

And to avoid warning

add below statement after `getch();` in main function.

```
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your function `void list_func(record);` as

```
void list_func(struct record);
```

Remove `return;` from function `void list_func(record list)`. You can't return from a `void` type function. Also add `return 0` just before the close braces of the `main`.